# Standard output in bash blocked by a line of code

Tags: python, bash, selenium-webdriver

I have a bash script in which I call a python script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python myscript.py
```

In the python script I'm using the selenium package to scrape:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
print('starting')
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://example.com"
browser.get(url)
...
```

I would like to run the bash script and get the output to the console and to a log file:

```
./bash_script.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

My problem is that this command never prints the expected message "starting" (or any other `print` in the python script), although the python script is indeed running.

BUT:

1. If I remove the `browser.get(url)` command, it works
2. If I call directly the python script (not through the bash script),
   it works
3. If I don't redirect the output and just call `./bash_script.sh`, it
           works

so it looks like there is a weird interaction between the bash redirection and this specific line of code `browser.get(url)`

Any idea why and how I can fix that?

Comment: I've set up the same env and run the shell. It worked. You miss something else it seems. It is written to `log.txt` as well.

Comment: Buffering issue? When your python script finishes there is no output at all?

Comment: @Poshi thank you so much that was it, adding the -u argument when calling my python script solved it. Not the first time I run into this problem but it seems to be very random (I'm calling other python scripts in my bash script and they all work fine)

Comment: @Poshi Please add your comment as an answer so Sulli can accept it so the question doesn't get left unanswered.

Comment: Well, I didn't gave an answer, just a hint/question to try to isolate the problem. Anyways, here is the answer with a little extra information,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffering issue? When your python script finishes there is no output at all?

If it is a buffering issue, `stdbuf` could help:

```
stdbuf -oL ./bash_script.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Comment: True. The `stdbuf` option is more general and works with any other command.